# Image smoothing using opencv data structures

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I would like to implement Gaussian blur on the AVI Files i read, i know about the in-built functions of opencv however i would need help from SO users to assist me so that i can get started by implementing it myself.

I know how to access the Image Pixels of an `IplImage *` , `CvARR *` , etc....

However i am just not sure how to begin. I know this is a very elementary question, but i would please please please request for patience and assistance from users out here and give me a way through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 month back I was also new to the opencv. The way I learn it is:

http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

http://www.packtpub.com/opencv-2-computer-vision-application-programming-cookbook/book

Comment: The openCV tutorials are much improved. Many of them now even build with the version of openCV they are included with!

Comment: There's also a good OpenCV book published by O'Reilly, if you can live with the C interface (as opposed to the newer C++ one). I'm halfway through the book and it has really helped raise my confidence with the library